# (C++) If - Else if statements for a CommandLine rock paper scissors game

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm fairly new to c++ but have been reading alot of documentation and cant figure out whats going on here. I've used if / else if statements on other things but maybe this is just a brain fart. i don't really know. when i type "1" when it ask's for an input and i press enter and it just goes directly to the Else statement

---

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char choice;
    int p2 = 2;
    int r1 = 1;
    int s3 = 3;


    //questions

    cout << "Lets Play Rock Paper Scissors" <<endl;
    cout << "(Use Letter) Rock (1) - Paper (2) - Scissors (3)" <<endl;
    que:
    cout << "What is your choice? : ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == p1){
        cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl;}
    else if (choice == p2){
        cout << "You choose Paper" <<endl;}
    else if (choice == s3){
        cout << "You choose Scissors" <<endl;}
    else
        goto que;


    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Make the type of choice as int. Also, you haven't declared p1 anywhere. I guess you meant r1. Thirdly, it is not advisable to use goto statements atleast for beginners. Lastly, instead of platform dependent and vulnerable system("PAUSE"), use std::cin.get().

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to compare a `char` to an `int`, which isn't going to work how you want it to, change the type of `choice` to `int`.

Also there's no variable called `p1`, that should probably be changed to `r1`.

Answer (score 1):

The characters for '1', '2' and '3' are not the same as the integers 1, 2 and 3. Under ascii encoding they will be 49, 50 and 51 for instance.

You can fix this by comparing the inputted character to the actual characters as follows:

```
char r1 = '1';
char p2 = '2';
char s3 = '3';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cin >> choice` is giving characters e.g. '1'. The character '1' is stored as a byte value of 49 and so when compared to the integer 1, the comparison fails.

iow:   '1' == 1 is equivalent to 49 == 1 which is false.

There are two ways you can fix this.

1) Change the type of choice to int:

```
int main()
{    
    int choice;
    int p2 = 2;
    int r1 = 1;
    int s3 = 3;
    ...
}
```

or 2) Change the type of p2, r1, s3 to char:

```
int main()
{    
    char choice;
    char p2 = '2';
    char r1 = '1';
    char s3 = '3';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration int r1=1; to int pa=1;. Hopefully it will work out.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned use int as type. Also I would not use goto, since it is bad practice. Furthermore, this looks like a perfect job for switch. Here is some altered code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int choice;
int p2 = 2;
int r1 = 1;
int s3 = 3;
//questions

cout << "Lets Play Rock Paper Scissors" <<endl;
for(;;) {
    cout << "(Use Letter) Rock (1) - Paper (2) - Scissors (3)" <<endl;
    cout << "What is your choice? : ";
    cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl; break;
            case 2: cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl; break;
            case 3: cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl; break;
            default: cout << "Unknown Option" << endl; break;
            }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing an int to a char? Also if that is all your code, string, cstdlib, and sstream libraries aren't used...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char choice;
    char rock = '1';
    char paper = '2';
    char scissors = '3';

    cout << "Let's play rock paper scissors\n";
    cout << "Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3\n";
    que:
    cout << "What is your choice? : ";

    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == rock)
    {
        cout << "You picked Rock!";
    }
    else if (choice == paper)
    {
        cout << "You picked Paper!";
    }
    else if (choice == scissors)
    {
        cout << "You picked Scissors!";
    }
    else
    {
        goto que;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the code is that the type of an object value of which is entered is `char`. So when you type for example `1` it is entered as character `'1'`. At the same time r1 has integral value 1. 
'1' is not equal to 1. When '1' is compared with 1 then there is compared the internal code of character '1'. For ASCII its value is 49. For EBCDIC its value is 241.
You could write for example

```
choice -= '0'; 
 if ( choice == r1 )
{
        cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl;
}
//...
```

you can write a test program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   char c = '1';
   int i  = 1;

   if ( c == i ) std::cout << ( int )c << " is equal to " << i << std::endl;
   else std::cout << ( int )c << " is not equal to " << i << std::endl;
}
```

I hope you will get result:)

```
49 is not equal to 1
```

Also take into account that your code has a typo. I think in this statement

```
if (choice == p1){
    cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl;}
```

there has to be `r1` instead of `p1`

```
if (choice == r1){
    cout << "You choose Rock" <<endl;}
```

Also it is a bad idea to use goto statement.

The program could look as

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char *name[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
    enum { Rock, Paper, Scissors };
    char choice;

    //questions

    std::cout << "Lets Play Rock Paper Scissors" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(Use Letter) " << name[Rock]     << " (" << Rock + 1     << ") - "
                                 << name[Paper]    << " (" << Paper + 1    << ") - "
                                 << name[Scissors] << " (" << Scissors + 1 << ")" << std::endl;

    do
    {
       std::cout << "What is your choice? : ";
       std::cin >> choice;

       switch ( choice - '0' - 1 )
       {
       case Rock:    
          std::cout << "You choose " << name[Rock] << std::endl;
          break;
       case Paper:
          std::cout << "You choose " << name[Paper] << std::endl;
          break;
       case Scissors:
          std::cout << "You choose " << name[Scissors] << std::endl;
          break;
       default:
          break; 
       }
    } while ( choice < '1' || choice > '3' );

    std::system( "PAUSE" );
}
```

EDIT: I updated some typos in the last program.